# Почему выводит none в консоль??? (python 3.7.8)

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль

Знаю, что если убрать print во второй строке эта вещь уходит.

```
def is_year_leap():
    year_input = str(input(print('Enter year: ')))
    year_div = int(year_input) % 4
    if year_div == 0:
        print('{} is leap year.'.format(year_input))

    else:
        return print('{} year is not leap year'.format(year_input))
is_year_leap()
```

Кто нибудь может объяснить почему выводит эту ошибку???

Comment: Только с високосным годом не все так просто `Год является високосным, если он кратен 4 и при этом не кратен 100 либо кратен 400`

Comment: Спасибо, учту почему то думал что каждые 4 года високосный год

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В строке

```
return print('{} year is not leap year'.format(year_input))
```

вы возвращаете то, что возвращает функция `print()`, а функция `print()` [*всегда возвращает `None`*](https://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/funkcii-print-v-python.html).

---

Вы наверно хотели вернуть строку — значит, удалите `print` из команды `return` и добавите еще одно `return`:

```
if year_div == 0:
    return '{} is leap year.'.format(year_input)

else:
    return '{} year is not leap year'.format(year_input)
```

Comment: Спасибо, за вашу ссылку на статью про принт.

Comment: @Diareich, не стоит.:-)

Answer (score 2):

В вашем коде input берет аргумент print('Enter year: '), функция print печатает Enter year: , а потом input печатает значение функции print, которая возвращает None.
Так же input возвращает тип str, поэтому не нужно прописывать str()

```
def is_year_leap():
    year_input = input('Enter year: ')
    year_div = int(year_input) % 4
    if year_div == 0:
        print('{} is leap year.'.format(year_input))

    else:
        print('{} year is not leap year'.format(year_input))
is_year_leap()
```

Answer (score 1):

смотрим строку `year_input = str(input(print('Enter year: ')))`

1. `str` - убираем, т.к. результат и так `str`

   `year_input = input(print('Enter year: '))`
2. так как вы написали, это все равно что:

   `val = print('Enter year: ')`

   `input(val)`

   посмотрите что такое `val`

   `print(val)`
3. пишем так:

   `year_input = input('Enter year: ')`